# Ubuntu as guest OS (with Vista host) stuck at 800x600 resolution

Tags: 10.04, virtualbox, guest-os

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Higher screen resolution in VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3205/higher-screen-resolution-in-virtualbox)

I believe I've successfully got Ubuntu 10.04 installed as the guest OS with Vista as host on my laptop. But I have been unable to get it to use the entire monitor. In Ubuntu and using the System-> Monitor Preferences, I have one monitor "Unknown" with a resolution of 800x600 and haven't found out how to change it to use the full 1920x1200 of my laptop.

I'm using Oracle's VM VirtualBox.

I am new to ubuntu (and *nix in general), so I could be missing something easy.

Comment: What virtual machine software are you using, e.g. QEMU, or VMware?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [install Guest Additions](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html) if you are using VirtualBox or a similar feature if it's some other virtualization software.