# Cannot set other resolution at VirtualBox guest: Elementary OS

Tags: boot, virtualbox, elementary

I've installed VirtualBox and also the extras that are posted here in other questions.
But I haven't managed to set a higher resolution.
The only ones that are available are:

- 1024x768
- 800x600

As mentioned at the question title, the host is Ubuntu 12.10, and the guest is Elementary OS Luna. What can I do?

Comment: Install the Guest Additions and reboot.

Comment: What is the video memory set to for the virtual machine?

Comment: @Jos: I've already installed them

Comment: @DavidOneill: The maximum, 128MB. Although my GPU has 1GB VRAM.

Comment: This link MAY help (or not)
http://askubuntu.com/questions/73589/higher-screen-resolution-for-virtualbox

If you look further down the page someone said that you may have to install the Guest Additions from inside VirtualBox (instead of from Ubuntu). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd suggest to update the Guest additions with the VM package manager.
So login first into your VM and open a Terminal to type:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11
```

Finally restart the VM to complete the installation.

You should get higher resolutions using the guest additions provided by the packages.

Comment: Its impossible atm to install virtualbox-guest-x11 due to held back packages. What now?

Answer (score 5):

As Sylvain already explained, you need to install guest-additions on the guest. This can be done as he suggested on Debian based guests but a more general approach is to press <kbd>Host</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or select the "Insert Guest Additions CD image" from the "Device" menu (shown here with an Ubuntu guest):

[image]

Once you have done that, follow the on screen instructions. The details may vary depending on the guest OS but this will always allow you to install Guest Additions, whatever the guest happens to be.

Answer (score 0):

This made (installing the guest additions) simple and quick for me..

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=15679