# How do you change display resolution of VMware Player in KDE Plasma 5?

Tags: kde, display-resolution, plasma, vmware-player

I installed the project NEON ppa in Ubuntu 14.04 to check out the new KDE in a VM. I can't seem to figure out how to change the display resolution. Its stuck at 800x600.

Edit: I'm using vmware player 6.0.3 with vmware tools installed. The unity desktop session runs at 1440x900. If I log out and switch to plasma5 session, its stuck at 800x600.

Comment: Same issue I am having with my Virtualbox guest. Ubuntu 14.04 with Plasma 5 packages installed. Both Unity and Plasma 5 have the same issue for me. I have tried downloading guest additions in virtualbox and devoting more resources to the VM. No luck

Comment: possible duplicate of [Higher screen resolution in VirtualBox?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3205/higher-screen-resolution-in-virtualbox)

Comment: im using vmware player. vmware-tools installed

Comment: It also happens to me. I have upgraded VMware Player to 6.0.4 build-2249910, and have tried open-vm-tools, but I get this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/open-vm-tools/+bug/1362631 Have you reported your bug to: - VMware? I suspect they support Ubuntu and not Kubuntu - Ubuntu (via Launchpad) - KDE (bugs.kde.org) I wonder if it is related to https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=337560 and Kubuntu does not have the fix yet.

Answer (score 7):

I have the same issue and have the following workaround:

It is possible to set the resolution from a command line using 'xrandr'. Running just  xrandr  allows you to see the current resolution and the other valid resolutions.

From a command line you can run  'xrandr -s 1024x768'  and the screen in VMware will reset to that size!

You can even set this at KDE startup by doing the following:

- click KDE start icon
- select System Settings
- select Startup and Shutdown
- click Add Program...
- enter 'xrandr -s 1024x768' in the text box
- be sure the "run in Terminal" checkbox is checked
- follow the rest of the prompts to set it as a startup command.

The next time you log in, it will start at 800x600 but at the end of the login you will see the screen resize!

Comment: Almost worked, but it reverts back to 800x600 right away still :(

Comment: @jocull, you probably did this, but... When you ran xrandr without operands, did you get a list of valid resolutions, and did you pick one of those?

Comment: I went back and tried this again just to be sure, but yes - I got a long list of valid resolutions and tried several, but they are reverted within a couple seconds at most.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much else to offer. I remember that one needed a later version of VMware to allow it to automatically resize, but this is 3 years back now and I don't recall... Good luck, and post if you find a solution!

Comment: It might just be a quirk of virtualbox :)

Answer (score 5):

If you try the `xrandr` command and it doesn't work:

- Power off the VM
- Go to display setting in Oracle VirtualBox and
- Change the graphics controller

It may take a couple of tries to find one that works.

Answer (score 2):

Go into the KDE menu and select **Settings**

Go to the **Workspace** section and look in the subsection labeled **Startup and Shutdown**

Go to the tab labeled **Background Services**. Look in the list that is located to the right and look for one that is titled *KScreen 2*

Locate the *pause* button for this service which is located to the right side of the screen right across from the *KScreen 2* label.

Click on the *pause* button then uncheck the box that is located to the left of the label *KScreen 2*, then click on the *apply* button at the bottom of that menu on the right side.

Then go to the **Display** tab and then select the screen resolution that you desire and then click on the *apply* button at the bottom on the right side of the screen.

Make sure that you save the settings because of the window management of KDE and the KScreen 2 service that is running in the background. Unless you are installing on bare metal the system cannot detect a virtual screen size in order to auto select a different resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Go to view → autosize → autofitguest in VMware vm window. Now stretch the vm VMware window and it will autosize for you