# Can't change resolution for KDE in Hyper-V VM

Tags: kubuntu, kde, display-resolution

Installed latest version of Kubuntu (17.10.1) 64-bit from https://kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/ into a VM under Hyper-V on Windows 10 Pro.

Resolution is stuck at 1152x864.  Too small to read things properly on websites and screen real estate is very poor.

Natively I'm running 2 monitors both at 1920x1080.

I was looking at this similar issue:  [How do you change display resolution in KDE Plasma 5?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/513036/how-do-you-change-display-resolution-in-kde-plasma-5)

However when I simply type `xrandr` into console to display resolutions I get this:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default  
Screen 0: minimum 1152 x 864, current 1152 x 864, maximum 1152 x 864  
default connected primary 1152x864+0+0 0mm x 0mm 1152x864       0.00*
```

And cannot use this command to change resolution because it says other resolutions are not found.

Any advice please?  Please go easy on me I haven't used any form of Linux in years so I'm pretty rusty.

Comment: Have you tried different settings via `System Settings` > `Display & Monitor`?

Comment: Thanks for response.  Yes I had checked there prior to looking up this issue.  The resolution is displayed on that screen but the drop down is grayed out and cannot be clicked.

Comment: What about https://askubuntu.com/questions/37411/screen-resolution-stuck-at-1024x768 ?

Comment: I had this issue. What fixed it for me was this post https://francescotonini.medium.com/how-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-on-hyper-v-with-enhanced-session-b20a269a5fa7