# Help - Newbie Installed virtual box on my Mac and then latest Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, resolution

This is driving me crazy!

Installed VirtualBox on my Mac Air, then Ubuntu latest - resolution of Ubuntu is STUCK at 640x480 which is way to small.

I head on over to settings/display and see 'Built in Display' in Pink.

For the life of me, I have been unable to change this, I click on the 640x480 and it highlights but that is all....

Is there a way to fix this?

Cheers

Comment: You need to install the [guest additions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm) in your guest to be able to change screen geometry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Higher screen resolution in VirtualBox?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3205/higher-screen-resolution-in-virtualbox) also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/12578/adjusting-display-geometry-in-a-virtual-machine