# VirtualBox: Display Size too small!! Can't reach or see anything, that includes the terminal!

Tags: virtualbox, display, resolution

Because I was tired of virtual box saying to update (even before I had a feeling it wouldn't be a good idea), I though well let's just get it over with...

I'm running Lubuntu 14.10 (32 bits the lastest) in Windows 8 (64 bits). My display size is literally a tiny tiny tiny box. I can only see right inferior corner, the date and the shutdown button. That's it. It's probably 3x3cm.
I had the guest additions, tried to "Auto-resize Guest display" nothing, tried to place 128Mb of video memory, nothing.
I had all my previous work in there, not that matters that much, but installing this again? No thank you.

I appreciate all the help! Thank you!

Screen Resolution: 64x768x32 @0,0

Here's some pics:
[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot1]

Comment: Stop swearing or you will be thrown out!

Comment: I'm so sorry! I'm usually not that aggressive, but I'm just really nervous about this. I changed my thread, thanks for giving a heads up.

Comment: What is the host?  Tell us if both are 32 or 64 bit.  How old was Vbox before you updated it?  Have you tried making a new machine from scratch and using the same virtual hard drive? In fact, can you successfully make any virtual machine with your new vbox?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Higher screen resolution in VirtualBox?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3205/higher-screen-resolution-in-virtualbox)

Comment: I updated the thread. My old VB version was 3.2.26 now it's 4.3.26, and yes I can create a new machine

Comment: @Fabby I can't access the terminal not even with the hotkeys

Comment: Which hotkeys?  [Ctr][Alt][F1] or [Ctrl][Alt][T]?

Comment: How were you able to install the guest additions in the Lubuntu virtual machine when the screen is not big enough to do anything?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I had everything setup before updating my VB.

Comment: When the VBOX software updates, there is pretty much always guest addition updates.  I am betting that your guest additions need to be updated, especially with such a huge jump in Vbox versions.  Did you have SSH set up so you can SSH in?  That's the first thing I set up on a VM.

Comment: @Fabby thanks, I did not used [Ctr][Alt][F1], which eliminates the graphical part. I'm now installing the codes from the thread you suggested.

Comment: So if you can get in with a terminal, I suggest updating the guest additions.

Comment: @OrganicMarble yep. It's possible but it's not like it gave me much a chance did it? Nonetheless I'm now installing the package from the thread suggested up here. I hope it works, I'll post results.

Comment: Okay, sorry for the wait, there were some corrupt packages that I had to upgrade and took forever. Okay so it's back on the default 1024x768, I can't change to fullscreen again. I would have to create another guest addition it's my guess, but I'd have to exit and unmount the previous .iso. Should I do that? When I try to create a new one the "Force unmount" doesn't do nothing.

Comment: Yes! Everything is working out! Thank you everyone!