# Ubuntu upgraded from 16.04 to 17.04, keyboard and usb don't work anymore

Tags: upgrade, usb, kernel, keyboard

Today I upgraded my Ubuntu distro from 16.04 to 17.04. Result: the keyboard and the usb ports don't work anymore.

I upgraded the distro via command line:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

It seems that I need to install a generic linux kernel.

Problem: if I run the installed version of Ubuntu I cannot install the kernel.

Can I install a kernel on my system from a live session?

Comment: How did you upgrade? What was 16 and what is "the latest"?

Comment: @Pilot6 post edited

Comment: It is not clear which version did you upgrade to which. Maybe upgrade was interrupted too.

Comment: @Pilot6 what is the deal with the versions? Anyway from 16.04 Lts to 17.04 (I thought this is the latest one)

Comment: There's no supported direct upgrade path from Ubuntu 16.04 to 17.04.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue following [these steps on the Ubuntu help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery#Update_Failure)

> #### Update Failure
>
> If there was an update that made your system non-bootable and they
> have fixed it in the repositories, you can use the Live CD to run
> apt-get to get the new files to fix your system.
>
> Boot the Ubuntu Live CD.   Press Ctrl-Alt-F1
>
> ```
> sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
> sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
> sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
> sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
> sudo chroot /mnt
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt upgrade
> ```

Then

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade -y && sudo apt install -y ubuntu-desktop*
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, upgraded from 16.04 to 17.o4 and found my keyboard no longer worked.

Found the fix here:

https://askubuntu.com/a/932041

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue after the upgrade.
After reading several posts, it seems that the issue is related to a missing package.

**1st** Start Ubuntu in recovery mode

**2nd** Select the Enable Networking option in the menu

**3rd** Now, select the root option and enter your root password (if set)

**4th** Configure your DNS
In the command line edit the file: /etc/resolv.conf
example: pico /etc/resolv.conf or vi /etc/resolv.conf
Add to the first line of the file.

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
```

Now save the file

**5th** install the missing package

***apt install xserver-xorg-input-all***

Finally restart your machine and your are good to go!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! In its current form your answer is not as good as it could be. Could you review [How to Write a Good Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659), and [Style guide for questions and answers](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/89/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers). Specifically the markdown editor supports numbered lists. Also Could you clarify why changing the dns would be needed?

Comment: Did help me - /etc/resolv.conf was not there and subsequently the apt install didn‘t work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. Luckily I was able to re-install 16.04 LTS and re-update to 17.04 on an old test laptop (HP EliteBook 8530p).

At the end of the update when it asks to remove obsolete packages, I simply chose `KEEP` and my mouse and keyboard worked after reboot.

Unfortunately, this solution only works if you find this answer before you dismiss that dialog and reboot. Otherwise, other solutions are required.