# Keyboard constant "Enter" key after 17.04 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, 17.04

I have a Lenovo ideapad 110-15ACL and I had Ubuntu 16.04 on it. I just ran the upgrade to 17.04 in hopes of resolving a wifi networking issue, but now I can't use the system to a different (and *much* stranger) issue.

I couldn't even log in because it looked like there was no keyboard, even if I plugged in an external. Then I used the "On screen keyboard" to log in.

Once I was ion, I opened a terminal - immediately, it filled up with "newlines".

Whenever I try to open a dialog or applicatioon, it behaves as though the "enter" key is being held down.

Let me state the obvious, there is nothing sitting on the keyboard.

During splash boot/shutdown, the escape key works, so I think this is only happening when I'm in Unity.

I can't, for the life of me, think of any ideas on how to resolve this.

Oh, and I can't SSH into it, for some reason. "Connection refused". I am pretty sure I installed SSH Server before this happened - not 100% though.

Mouse works just fine.

Looking for ideas on WTH is going on and maybe how to resolve it.

Thanks,

--mobrien118

Comment: New info - pulled the hard drive and booted into it in VirtualBox on a completely separate PC and it is doing the same thing - so it looks like a software issue, rather than hardware. Since I can get into the filesystem, but can't get into a running system, any ideas on what to disable to get the keyboard to stop freaking out?

Comment: Same exact problem here. Upgraded from 16.04 to 17.04 to try to resolve a wifi issue on thinkpad. Now I get constant newlines and no keyboard input. I had to enter the password with the on screen keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to install xserver-xorg-input-all and then it worked. See the answer here:

[Updated from 16.04 to 16.10; the keyboard and mouse no longer works after getting to the lock screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908918/updated-from-16-04-to-16-10-the-keyboard-and-mouse-no-longer-works-after-gettin)