# mouse and keyboard not working after upgrdading from 16.04 to 17.04

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, mouse

I upgraded from 16.04 to 17.04 and my mouse and keyboard are not workingon my desktop.  What do I do?

External mouse and keyboard don't work.  Windows 10 works fine when I boot up in the windows partition so it's not the hardware.  Short of deleting the partition and starting over any suggestions?  Or is that what I have to do?

Comment: Are these PS/2 mouse/keyboard, or USB?

Comment: USB.  Problem is clearly the OS.  Works fine I  windows 10, and other mice and keyboards

Comment: Are the USB keyboard and mouse plugged directly into a computer port, or through a hub or extender? In the BIOS, is the USB set to legacy, or something else? I assume that they worked in 16.04?

Comment: I have the same problem. Upgraded 16.04 LTS to 17.04, and now neither mouse nor keyboard work anymore. They are USB, connected directly to the PC. They worked in 16.04, and they still work in Windows. Anyone have any idea how this is possible and how to fix it?

Comment: I was able to get the keyboard and mouse to work by following the instructions in the top answer to this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/908918/updated-from-16-04-to-16-10-the-keyboard-and-mouse-no-longer-works-after-gettin