# Boot into Grub with an encrypted disk

Tags: boot, grub2, encryption

I recently spun up a Linux PC with full disk encryption (I checked the box during install).  I then tried tried to fix a trackpad issue by installing xserver

`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

Now my keyboard doesn't work after boot up and my mouse works for about 10 seconds.  I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908918/updated-from-16-04-to-16-10-the-keyboard-and-mouse-no-longer-works-after-gettin) post about fixing it from Grub, but I'm having trouble booting into GRUB.  Is that because I have disk encryption?  Am I doomed?

Comment: Can you connect over `ssh`? That would make things a bit easier.

Comment: I'm not sure.  I'm trying to figure out how to find its IP address--it's a laptop without a network port, so I can't just plug straight in to it.

Comment: Do you have access to the router? It should give you the IP address. Other than that you could use Wireshark and look for it's DHCP request and/or any traffic from it. Ping its hostname?

Comment: I'm getting a "Connection refused" error.  I didn't mess with whatever the default ssh settings would have been.