# Mistake configuring Wacom drivers causes wireless keyboard to stop working

Tags: keyboard, xorg, wacom

I have an old Bamboo Wacom tablet I got working properly by manually installing the drivers from the [Linux Wacom Project](https://linuxwacom.github.io/). Everything worked beautifully after that, until I rebooted. Then the keyboard and mouse didn't work, only the tablet.

I managed to load the system using the accessibility keyboard with the tablet, and I ran `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all` to get back the mouse. An old backup wired keyboard also works, but not my wireless keyboard I was using before. And the tablet doesn't work at all now.

The only thing I did differently than the instructions for installing the Wacom drivers was with the [xf86-input-wacom driver](https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/Building-The-Driver) When I tried `sudo -s 'apt-get update && apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-wacom'`, it didn't understand the command, so I split it in two, running `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-wacom` and then `sudo apt-get update`.

I could really use both of these devices, the old wired keyboard is gigantic and crusty, with several sticky keys, and I was working on artwork we need with the tablet.

How should I proceed from here?

Comment: This is a known bug w/ drawing tablets:  Once you install the tablet driver, please follow the top answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908918/updated-from-16-04-to-16-10-the-keyboard-and-mouse-no-longer-works-after-gettin) to reconfigure xorg from within recovery mode.  ALSO: The 'sudo -s' command is not a valid command, that's why you got an error.   Remember to **always** update your repositories first before installing software: so the correct order for those commands are: `sudo apt udpate` *and then* `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-wacom`

Comment: @Nmath Thank you, but it didn't work. The tablet began to work, but the wireless keyboard never works. Also the tablet sometimes stops working. I tried twice through recovery mode to fix things with no improvement. I am wondering about removing the drivers to start over.