# No keyboard/mouse input on Login Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, xorg, xserver, xinput

I've been having a super bizarre problem recently. About a week ago, I reinstalled Ubuntu on my dual-booted Dell XPS 15, since my keyboard and mouse were not working. The os itself was still fine (ie it wasn't frozen), but neither external keyboards/mice nor my internal keyboard/touchpad were responsive. After a week, it looks like the problem has occurred again on a relatively fresh install of Ubuntu.

I have tried reinstalling `xserver` and `xserver-input` as talked about in this question: [Updated from 16.04 to 16.10; the keyboard and mouse no longer works after getting to the lock screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908918/updated-from-16-04-to-16-10-the-keyboard-and-mouse-no-longer-works-after-gettin)

Digging into it a bit, I noticed that there was a package named `xserver-xorg-input-all` and `xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-18.04`. What are their differences, and what should I have installed?

This happened after a reboot of my system, and I don't remember installing or removing anything specifically. Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: If you make a LiveUSb with Xubuntu 19.10 and boot from it, does the problem repeat?

Comment: No, the keyboard and mouse work on everything else

Comment: OK, we're making progress. If you make a LiveUSB with 18.04 LTS, does the problem repeat?

Comment: No, it is an issue with only my version. I would normally just reinstall Ubuntu to save time, but it is a repeated issue, and I would like to find out what went wrong so I know not to do it again. I am able to get into recovery mode, which is how I've been testing different things.

Comment: OK. This particular installation of 18.04 has the issue, and now we need to find what's amiss. Agreed?

Comment: Yes, and it's the second time it has happened, so it isn't a fluke. It's personal now 

Answer (score -1):

Did u checked any other on that same port (eg..speaker)

working or not

*ctrl+alt+t

*sudo apt-get update press enter give yes

*sudo apt-get upgrade press enter

*reboot and check now

Comment: Yes, I have tried to update all the packages. As for the same port, no input device works. This includes mice, keyboards, touchpad, touchscreen, etc.