# Keyboard and mouse stops working

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, mouse

After restart of my laptop with Lubuntu (18.x) I got sad surprise. My keyboard and mouse stop working. First, I plug-in external keyboard and mouse, but they did not work too. So I guess that it is rather software issue.

I followed steps from this topic: [Updated from 16.04 to 16.10; the keyboard and mouse no longer works after getting to the lock screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908918/updated-from-16-04-to-16-10-the-keyboard-and-mouse-no-longer-works-after-gettin)

But unfortunately it did not help to me.

I focused on this answer:

```
I had the same issue today and found this bug report.

The problem seems to be, that during update process they forget to install/update the package `xserver-xorg-input-all`!

So these instructions worked for me on my thinkpad p51s notebook with a little modification:

    Press a Shift key during boot to get the GRUB menu.
    In GRUB, select Advanced Options, then the first kernel with the recovery mode.
    Select "Network" to get network access (needed for package installation)
    Select "Drop to root shell"
    Press Enter to confirm.
    On my system not needed because, the filesystem was mounted rw, but if needed then mount -o rw,remount /.
    Install the needed package: apt install xserver-xorg-input-all (and the message that they need to uninstall 16.04 packages!)
    Press Ctrl+D to leave the root shell.
    Select resume boot from the menu.
    Now I could only log into console.
    sudo reboot

After reboot my ThinkPad's mouse and keyboard and the external mouse and keyboard worked fine!
```

But I dont have the same options visible, as that user said. Now, I am preparing bootable usb with Lubuntu 20, but substantially it would be comfortable to stay on current Lubuntu and not wasting hours of time on configuring OS from the beginning.

Comment: Lubuntu 18.x?   no such release. Lubuntu 18.04 LTS runs LXDE and Lubuntu 18.10 is LXQt so please be specific. All Lubuntu releases are desktop & *deb* based so use *yy.mm* format, none are *snap* based which use *yy* format.

Comment: It is Lubuntu 18.04 LTS on LXDE. My mistake, I thoight that it is not big diference between 18.xx versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the update on Lubuntu 16.04 (yes, I am near end of it's lifetime) I lost my keyboard. I saw in the update details GRUB was updated. And during boot a message "keyboard not detected".

I read some 30 threads about this ranging from 2014 to now. Checked that the keyboard worked fine in the bios. I didn't want to spend much time on this anymore, so I downloaded Puppy Linux life distro, started it, and used it to install GRUB4DOS on the harddrive.

I still have my dual boot Windows10/Lubuntu16.04.

GRUB will be usefull for something...but grub4dos always works.

Comment: FYI: Lubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (https://lubuntu.me/xenial-5-released/ http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Lubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved this problem by myself.
The solution from the linked topic in my question works perfectly, but I have a notebook with an only a wireless interface, so the command `apt install xserver-xorg-input-all` cannot be executed correctly, because of no internet connection.
Because this computer does not have a LAN card, I shared internet access from my phone, by USB cable. Then `xserver-xorg-input-all` was downloaded and installed.