# After login, nothing works. no mouse move no keyboard. nothing. New 22.4.2 update problem. I think it just came out yesterday

Tags: updates, xorg

I'm not a Linux user. This problem occurred after I updated Ubuntu 22.4.2 to the new version that probably came out yesterday on may/22/2023. I'm using Hyper-V Virtual Machine. Everything freezes after login. nothing works and there is nothing except the wallpaper on the screen. I can use key combinations to open that black command-based page with ctrl + alt + f1 and ctrl + alt + f3. it asks me for username and password. It does not accept credentials though. I think it freezes mid work. I have also tried locking the screen with ctrl + alt + f1 and login again. But after a few seconds of working. it freezes again. I have restarted several times and it has not worked. I don't have a GPU on my pc so it's not the GPU driver issue with Nvidia that some may say. I also used this Link:( [Updated from 16.04 to 16.10; the keyboard and mouse no longer works after getting to the lock screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908918/updated-from-16-04-to-16-10-the-keyboard-and-mouse-no-longer-works-after-gettin) ) to solve the issue. the problem is using SHIFT does not work at startup. So, I tried using those few seconds to Enter the Command:( apt install xserver-xorg-input-all ). and it said I already have it installed. The same problem has happened on my laptop too. after the update nothing works. what should I do? I have no restore points either. If there is a rollback option, please guide me. the update has come out very recently. I don't know the number. But I'm sure you guys know.

Answer (score 2):

It does look like this is a recent kernel update.  I've got around this by installing and using kernel 5.19.0-41-generic.

From frozen screen use CTRL+ALT+F3 to jump to text mode and login.
You can then use following to install the lower kernel
sudo apt install linux-image-5.19.0-41-generic.

You might also need to adjust your grub settings so you can select the kernel at boot time.

Sudo nano /etc/default/grub

I then changed
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10

Once you save a quick I then use
sudo update-grub

and then sudo reboot

You should then have an Advanced options for Ubuntu that you can choose and from there you can select the 5.19.0-41 Kernel.

Can't guarantee it won't break anything down the line but it's got me into my test Ubuntu VM.

Comment: thanks, I went back to 5.15 something kernel in the advanced option, and solved the issues.