# Kubuntu resolution stuck at (800x600) in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, kubuntu, display-resolution

Linux newbie - I have recently installed Kubuntu into VirtualBox (on my laptop) to play around with, but I cannot get Kubuntu to go to a higher resolution.

VirtualBox setup:

- Base Memory = 4gb
- Video Memory = 64Mb
- Graphics Controller = VMSVGA

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated
cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Higher screen resolution in VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3205/higher-screen-resolution-in-virtualbox)

Comment: Looks lke i have fixed it:   Changed the VirtualBox Graphics Controller to VBoxSVGA - started Kubuntu again and this time it was accepted higher Resolutions and kept them.

Comment: Excellent! Good to hear it. =)

Comment: Switching the VirtualBox Graphics Controller to VBoxSVGA also fixed things for me. (I've never had this problem before with Ubuntu, first time I've install Kubuntu) @Smac - could you add you fix as a answer, then it can be upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

Just right click on the image of the monitor in the bottom right of your running VM and then change the resolution to the desired one.

[image: Scale and Resize options list]

I struggled too to figure it out ;)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like i have fixed it:
I have changed the VirtualBox Graphics Controller to **VMSVGA** - started Kubuntu again and this time it was accepted higher Resolutions and kept them.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but +1 because you brought me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to install the VirtualBox's Guest Additions CD image? This can resolve your problem I think.

If you didn't install it, follow this procedure:

- Run your VM.
- Then go to the Virtual Box's menu and under *Devices* select *Insert Guest additions Cd Image*.
- Once the Image is inserted, go to `/media/<your_user>/VBox_GAs_6.0.14/` and run the script `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` with root privileges (`sudo`).

After the script execution your VM will (normally) adapt the resolution automatically.

Comment: Good answer. Note that VBoxLinuxAdditions will require gcc to be installed. You can install the most essential and used build tools using `sudo apt install build-essential` before running the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "Configured Video Device"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier "Monitor0"
VendorName "KDS"
ModelName "VS-7e"
HorizSync 30-70
VertRefresh 50-120
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "Screen0"
Device "Configured Video Device"
Monitor "Monitor0"
DefaultDepth 24
SubSection "Display"
Viewport 0 0
Depth 24
Modes "1024x768"
EndSubSection
EndSection
```

write the code above and save the file as `xorg.conf` in virtualbox.