# VirtualBox screen resize impossible

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I am running a Ubuntu machine (version 18.04.4) with VirtualBox.
The screen resolution is locked on 800x600 and this is uncomfortable.

Like write on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3205/higher-screen-resolution-in-virtualbox), I've already installed virtualbox additions :

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11 virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

When I restart the vm, I can change the screen resolution (View -> Virtual Screen 1 -> Resize to ...).

But my keyboard and my mouse don't worked except on lock screen. To resolve this problem, I followed [this tutorial](https://techwiser.com/fix-keyboard-not-working-in-ubuntu-18-04/#ubuntu-command). And then I had to reboot the system.

But, even if I don't change anything, when I reboot the machine, the screen size come back to 800x600 and I cannot change the resolution anymore.

I checked if the packages were still installed (by running `dpkg --list`) and they were well installed. I tried to remove and reinstall them but it's not working either.

I tried to run (Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD images...) but i've got [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbX2r.png)

I did it like 4 times and i have the problem at each try. Any idea ?

Comment: The last error is because of guest additions is is mounted already.

Comment: did I unterstood well, ubuntu is guest?

Comment: Yep, my vm is running with ubuntu, but my computer is on windows